# Why is SharedPreferences persisting after reinstall in Android Studio using emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, sharedpreferences, persistence

In my understanding, SharedPreferences data is not supposed to persist after a reinstall. I have coded the logic of my app accordingly.

However, using testing on an emulator in Android Studio, I'm seeing the SharedPreferences persist even after I rebuild and reinstall the app. This occurs even if I close and restart the emulator.

Can anyone explain this (seemingly) odd behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` are stored in your internal data directory in XML files. As long as you don't delete your application, these files persist.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref):

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

Comment: Why doesn't closing and restarting the emulator remove those files? Is the only way to simulate a fresh install to manually delete the XML files that store the SharedPreferences data?

Comment: @RobertMcLendon I would say so. Or just uninstall the app before reinstallation.

Comment: Seems there's a bug in Marshmallow that preserves the data on the device even after full uninstall, when backup is set to off.